# Lambda in android studio

Tags: java, android

Got confused about lambda in android studio

I wanted to create a listener for a button in android studio and coded this:

```
ButtonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("On click test"));
            }
        });
```

And it's working but IDE suggested to use lambda like this:

`ButtonName.setOnClickListener((view) -> System.out.println("On click test"));`

And it also works and I got interested into lambda and want to know if I understand it.

It works because function *View.OnClickListener()* has only one abstract Method *onClick* so lambda automaticly uses *onClick* method ?
I'm a little confused about lambda.

Comment: That's correct.  If OnClickListener had multiple functions, you wouldn't be able to use a lambda.  A lambda can only be used where it's replacing an interface with a single function.

Comment: Okay thank you @GabeSechan